# Using LINQ to loop through each index of an array and bind to a datasource

Tags: linq, list, loops, indexing, datasource

The following code works fine but it is only writing the last index[] to the datasource.  I am having a hard time finding an elegant way to loop through each index and add/append it to the var mydata.  It is a dynamic query, some may have zero indexes and some may have 5 or more...

My desired result would look something like this:

DetailsView1

ServerName: Server1, Server2, Server3

ServerIP: IP1, IP2, IP3

ServerState: State1, State2, State3

I am also up for other suggested methods, I am still a n00b at this coding stuff :)

Example:

```
if (result.Server.servicename !=null && result.Server.servicename.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string str in result.Server.servicename)
                        {
                            List<NetScalerResult> res = new NetScalerService(env).GetService(str);

                        var mydata = from r in res
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         Name = r.Services.name,
                                         ServerName = r.Services.servername,
                                         ServerIP = r.Services.ipaddress,
                                         ServerState = r.Services.svrstate,
                                         Port = r.Services.port,
                                         ServiceType = r.Services.servicetype,
                                         ClientTimeout = r.Services.clttimeout,
                                         ServerTimeout = r.Services.svrtimeout
                                     };

                        DetailsView1.DataSource = mydata;
                        DetailsView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
```

Thanks!!
David

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the question. But it looks like you are data binding inside the foreach loop, which effectively overwrites the data binding from the previous iteration. So at the end, you are left with only the last entry being data-bound.

An easy was to fix this, is to collect the mydatas into a list and then data-bind that list.

Comment: what is the best way to collect the mydatas to a list?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @tunedportcj5: If mydata can have more than one entry, use `list.AddRange(mydata);`. Otherwise put in a single - i.e. `var mydata = (query).Single();` and then use `list.Add(mydata);`. You'll need an appropriate list structure outside the loop, i.e. `var list = new List<...>();`. Then move the data-binding outside the loop. Of course, the DetailsView needs to understand this new list as well - I don't know, what kind of schema you have for that.

Comment: @tunedportcj5: But maybe I misunderstood your question. I don't quite see, how you could get the desired output by using that query.

Comment: @tunedportcj5: Try writing out what you want to achieve with ordinary foreach statements. Then it will be simpler to see, what you actually want to achieve. I suspect, LINQ is not the way to go here (readability-wise)